# MediaElement.js — Splash screen before playing video

Tags: html5-video, splash-screen, mediaelement.js

Is it possible to load an image in the player before the play button is pressed? I know this is possible with Flash, but I haven't had any luck finding information about this for MediaElement.js.

To say it a different way, I want to show something in the player besides the black box before anyone clicks on it (similar to Youtube, Vimeo, or most other video players).

Answer (score 1):

I was going about this the wrong way. Rather than banging my head against a wall trying to force a splash screen into MediaElement.js, I started looking at the html5 video element. As it turns out, video allows you to pass in a "poster", which is basically the splash screen.

Here's an example:

```
<video width="800" height="480" src="/path/to/my-awesome-cat-video.mp4" poster="/path/to/cat-splash.png">
```